# Looping through multiple arrays & concatenating values in pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I've a dataframe with list of items separated by `, commas` as below.

```
+----------------------+
|        Items         |
+----------------------+
| X1,Y1,Z1             |
| X2,Z3                |
| X3                   |
| X1,X2                |
| Y2,Y4,Z2,Y5,Z3       |
| X2,X3,Y1,Y2,Z2,Z4,X1 |
+----------------------+
```

Also I've 3 list of arrays which has all items said above clubbed into specific groups as below

`X = [X1,X2,X3,X4,X5]
 Y = [Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4,Y5]
 Z = [Z1,Z2,Z3,Z4,Z5]`

my task is to split the each value in the dataframe & check individual items in the 3 arrays and if an item is in any of the array, then it should concatenate the name of the groups which it is found, separated with `&`. Also if many items are in the same group/array, then it should mention the number of occurrence as well.

My desired output is as below. refer `Category` column

```
+----------------------+--------------+
|        Items         |   Category   |
+----------------------+--------------+
| X1,Y1,Z1             | X & Y & Z    |
| X2,Z3                | X & Z        |
| X3                   | X            |
| X1,X2                | 2X           |
| Y2,Y4,Z2,Y5,Z3       | 3Y & 2Z      |
| X2,X3,Y1,Y2,Z2,Z4,X1 | 3X & 2Y & 2Z |
+----------------------+--------------+
```

X,Y, and Z are the name of the arrays.
how shall I start to solve this using pandas? please guide.

Comment: Is this your exact problem or are `X1`, `X2`,... stand-in values for something else? That can impact how we solve your problem. One hacky way to solve it with your problem as stated is to strip off all the digits and unique the remaining strings

Comment: @CodeDifferent no. these are examples. also i have 16 arrays. i mentioned here only 3. X,Y,Z

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['X1,Y1,Z1'],
      ['X2,Z3'],
      ['X3'],
      ['X1,X2'],
      ['Y2,Y4,Z2,Y5,Z3'],
      ['X2,X3,Y1,Y2,Z2,Z4,X1']],
    columns=['Items']
)

X = ['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5']
Y = ['Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3', 'Y4', 'Y5']
Z = ['Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3', 'Z4', 'Z5']
```

---

#### `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

M = {**dict.fromkeys(X, 'X'), **dict.fromkeys(Y, 'Y'), **dict.fromkeys(Z, 'Z')}

num = lambda x: {1: ''}.get(x, x)
cat = ' & '.join
fmt = lambda c: cat(f'{num(v)}{k}' for k, v in c.items())
cnt = lambda x: Counter(map(M.get, x.split(',')))

df.assign(Category=[*map(fmt, map(cnt, df.Items))])

                  Items      Category
0              X1,Y1,Z1     X & Y & Z
1                 X2,Z3         X & Z
2                    X3             X
3                 X1,X2            2X
4        Y2,Y4,Z2,Y5,Z3       3Y & 2Z
5  X2,X3,Y1,Y2,Z2,Z4,X1  3X & 2Y & 2Z
```

---

## OLD STUFF

#### `pandas.Series.str.get_dummies` and `groupby`

First convert the definitions of `X`, `Y`, and `Z` into one dictionary, then use that as the argument for `groupby` on `axis=1`

```
M = {**dict.fromkeys(X, 'X'), **dict.fromkeys(Y, 'Y'), **dict.fromkeys(Z, 'Z')}

counts = df.Items.str.get_dummies(',').groupby(M, axis=1).sum()
counts

   X  Y  Z
0  1  1  1
1  1  0  1
2  1  0  0
3  2  0  0
4  0  3  2
5  3  2  2
```

Add the desired column
**Work in Progress** I don't like this solution

```
def fmt(row):
    a = [f'{"" if v == 1 else v}{k}' for k, v in row.items() if v > 0]
    return ' & '.join(a)

df.assign(Category=counts.apply(fmt, axis=1))

                  Items      Category
0              X1,Y1,Z1     X & Y & Z
1                 X2,Z3         X & Z
2                    X3             X
3                 X1,X2            2X
4        Y2,Y4,Z2,Y5,Z3       3Y & 2Z
5  X2,X3,Y1,Y2,Z2,Z4,X1  3X & 2Y & 2Z
```

---

#### NOT TO BE TAKEN SERIOUSLY

Because I'm leveraging the character of your contrived example and there is nowai you should depend on the first character of your values to be the thing that differentiates them.

```
from operator import itemgetter

df.Items.str.get_dummies(',').groupby(itemgetter(0), axis=1).sum()

   X  Y  Z
0  1  1  1
1  1  0  1
2  1  0  0
3  2  0  0
4  0  3  2
5  3  2  2
```

Comment: Thank you.! it works, but i get a completely different dataframe. however i need to plug the data into the original dataframe. as i mentioned in the desired output.

Comment: accepted your latest answer. which works well in my actual dataset.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming a column of `list`s, `explode` the lists, then this is a simple `isin` check that we sum along the original index. I'd suggest a different output, which gets across the same information but is much easier to work with in the future.

#### Example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Items': [['X1', 'Y1', 'Z1'], ['X2', 'Z3'], ['X3'],
                             ['X1', 'X2'], ['Y2', 'Y4', 'Z2', 'Y5', 'Z3'],
                             ['X2', 'X3', 'Y1', 'Y2', 'Z2', 'Z4', 'X1']]})
X = ['X1','X2','X3','X4','X5']
Y = ['Y1','Y2','Y3','Y4','Y5']
Z = ['Z1','Z2','Z3','Z4','Z5']
```

---

```
s = df.explode('Items')['Items']
pd.concat([s.isin(l).sum(level=0).rename(name) 
           for name, l in [('X', X), ('Y', Y), ('Z', Z)]], axis=1).astype(int)
#   X  Y  Z
#0  1  1  1
#1  1  0  1
#2  1  0  0
#3  2  0  0
#4  0  3  2
#5  3  2  2
```

---

To get your output, mask the 0s and add the columns names after the values. Then we string join to get the result. Here I use an apply for simplicity, alignment and NaN handling, but there are other slightly faster alternatives.

```
res = pd.concat([s.isin(l).sum(level=0).rename(name) 
                 for name, l in [('X', X), ('Y', Y), ('Z', Z)]], axis=1).astype(int)

res = res.astype(str).replace('1', '').where(res.ne(0))
res = res.add(res.columns, axis=1)

# Aligns on index due to `.sum(level=0)`
df['Category'] = res.apply(lambda x: ' & '.join(x.dropna()), axis=1) 
#                          Items      Category
#0                  [X1, Y1, Z1]     X & Y & Z
#1                      [X2, Z3]         X & Z
#2                          [X3]             X
#3                      [X1, X2]            2X
#4          [Y2, Y4, Z2, Y5, Z3]       3Y & 2Z
#5  [X2, X3, Y1, Y2, Z2, Z4, X1]  3X & 2Y & 2Z
```

Comment: Thank you.! it works, but i get a completely different dataframe. however i need to plug the data into the original dataframe. as i mentioned in the desired output.

Comment: Do you want it formatted in exactly the way you've presented it? @Rapto

Comment: @ALollz let me plug into my actual dataframe & come back to you

Comment: @ALollz there really isn't q-:

Comment: @piRSquared yes please. my real data set is so huge. i gave example of X,Y and Z. but, precisely it has 16 arrays. where array elements are different. agan i mentioned x1,x2.x3, for ease of reference. i have around 35 elements in each array

Comment: ALollz although your answer is elegant. I'm not getting the right output in my actual dataset. hence, i accept @piRSquared answer. Thank you and upvoted

Comment: @ALollz I don't receive the correct answer which is supposed to get when after running the code in the actual data set.. (i checked manually too). not all but some data points. around 10% i would say i didn't save the exact recon i did on the errors to show you.

Comment: @Rapto Ah that's fine, though unfortunate. The only major issue I can think of would be a duplicated Index in your original DataFrame, but otherwise so long as piR's answer works that's encouraging!

Answer (score 2):

Create your dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Items': [['X1', 'Y1', 'Z1'], 
                            ['X2', 'Z3'], 
                            ['X3'], 
                            ['X1', 'X2'], 
                            ['Y2', 'Y4', 'Z2', 'Y5', 'Z3'],
                            ['X2', 'X3', 'Y1', 'Y2', 'Z2', 'Z4', 'X1']]})
```

explode

```
df_exp = df.explode('Items')

def check_if_in_set(item, set):
    return 1 if (item in set) else 0

dict = {'X': set(['X1','X2','X3','X4','X5']),
        'Y': set(['Y1','Y2','Y3','Y4','Y5']), 
        'Z': set(['Z1','Z2','Z3','Z4','Z5'])}

for l, s in dict.items():
    df_exp[l] = df_exp.apply(lambda row: check_if_in_set(row['Items'], s), axis=1)
```

groupby

```
df_exp.groupby(df_exp.index).agg(
    Items_list = ('Items', list),
    X_count = ('X', 'sum'),
    y_count = ('Y', 'sum'),
    Z_count = ('Z', 'sum')
)

                      Items_list  X_count  y_count  Z_count
0                   [X1, Y1, Z1]        1        1        1
1                       [X2, Z3]        1        0        1
2                           [X3]        1        0        0
3                       [X1, X2]        2        0        0
4           [Y2, Y4, Z2, Y5, Z3]        0        3        2
5  [X2, X3,  Y1, Y2, Z2, Z4, X1]        3        2        2
```

Comment: Thank you.! it works, but i get a completely different dataframe. however i need to plug the data into the original dataframe. as i mentioned in the desired output.